# App Engine Standard Python 3 environment variables undefined

Tags: python, google-app-engine, environment-variables

I am trying to access the GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT environment variable in my App Engine Standard Python 3 app. According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#environment_variables) this variable should be set at runtime. I created a simple function using Flask to demonstrate the issue:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def root():
    try:
        return GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT
    except NameError:
        return 'GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT undefined'
```

Whatever I try I keep triggering the exception and 'GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT undefined' is returned. Why am I not able to access this environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By just looking at the code you provide, the reason is that this is not the way to get the value of an Environment Variable using Python. Actually, the error message you would see if you didn't have the `except` is that the variable `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` does not exist in your Python code.

You may want to use something like this:

```py
from flask import Flask
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def root():
    try:
        return os.environ['GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT']
    except NameError:
        return 'GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT undefined'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```